# Two differed v-on:clicks within same element

Tags: vue.js

So, the first v-on click works, but when I try and trigger the one below it, nothing happens. I'm assuming you can't really nest different `onclicks` like this? I can't just use the same `v-on click` in this case because the added class will trigger a different behaviour.

```
 <div id="menu">
    <div class="menu" v-on:click="toggle" v-bind:class="{ active: isActive }">
        Hey
        <div class="m-items animated slideInRight" v-on:click="change" v-bind:class="{ display: display }">
            <ul>
                <li><i class="fa fa-toggle-off" aria-hidden="true"></i>Hey</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

var menu = new Vue({
  el: '#menu',
  data: {
    isActive: false,
  },

  methods: {
    toggle: function(event) {
      this.isActive = !this.isActive
    }
  }
})

var displayList = new Vue({
  el: '.m-items',
  data: {
    display: false,
  },

  methods: {
    change: function(event) {
      this.display = !this.display
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [event modifiers](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Event-Modifiers) with `v-on:click` to stop propagation of click events in your case, you can do it like following:

```
<div id="menu">
    <div class="menu" v-on:click="toggle" v-bind:class="{ active: isActive }">
        Hey
        <div class="m-items animated slideInRight" v-on:click.stop="change" v-bind:class="{ display: display }">
            <ul>
                <li><i class="fa fa-toggle-off" aria-hidden="true"></i>Hey</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hmm this doesn't work...it looks like the "toggle" click just overrides and doesn't allow the change to trigger even after adding "stop," but thanks for your help

Comment: I also tried adding "self" to the "toggle" one as well (which I hoped would not affect children, but no luck)